# difference between phase difference and path difference?

Tags: waves, interference

I've read up on many websites and I've even looked on this stack exchange but I still don't understand the difference between phase difference and path difference.
Can you please explain what each means and then state the difference(s). Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The path difference is the actual physical length that an ray of light for instance has to travel more than another ray of light. The phase difference is then just a convenient way of incorporating this value into trigonometric functions. It is defined as

$\delta = 2\pi \Delta l /\lambda$

Hence the phase difference is an angular measure that refers to how much two waves are "out of sync". A phase difference of $\pi /2$ for example means that one wave is at a maximum while the other is at 0.  Depending on the wavelength of those waves, you can derive the path length difference.

So if I had waves of a wavelength $\lambda = 1$m, then a phase difference of $\pi$ would result from a path length difference of 50cm.

This of course only applies if the sources are producing waves in phase. Otherwise, say when one produces a peak the other produces a trough, this is already considered a phase difference but there is no path length difference responsible for it.

Comment: Also, you can cause a phase difference by having two sources at the same frequency but different phases, even if there is no path difference.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Jaywalker Can you please explain the final sentence in your answer because that confused me a bit.

Comment: It just means that at any point in time the amplitude of the wave at one of the sources is not the same as at the other source